# Rewriting a query

Tags: postgresql, query, performance, query-performance

I have a database with the following structure (star schema):

```
facttable:

  pros integer
  mena integer
  me integer
  vahet double precision
  slutttp timestamp without time zone
```

Structure of each dimension table is:

```
  "name" character varying(40),
  id integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT dim_me_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

My fact table is huge with several billion rows and the dimension tables contain several thousand rows.

I use a tool to write queries (tableausoftware.com), this means that I cannot write my queries intelligently. And I have to use that tool. So my solution was to rewrite the queries which are generated by that tool.

For ex.

Original query:

```
select dim_me.name, 
       case when  
          dim_me.name like 'k%' then ‘something’ 
          else ‘egg’ 
       end as egg, 
       sum(facttable.vahet) 
from dim_me, facttable
where dim_me.id = facttable.me group by name;
```

Needless to say, such a query is simply hopelessly suboptimal. Therefore in order to increase the performance, I rewrite the above  query as:

```
select dim_me.name, 
       case 
           when dim_me.name like 'k%' then 'something' 
           else 'egg' 
       end as egg, 
       sum_vahet 
 from (
    select me, 
           sum(vahet) as sum_vahet 
    from facttable
    group by me
 ) as result_table 
 inner join dim_me on (dim_me.id = result_table.me);
```

My question if  there is better way to rewrite this query in order to gain performance speed.

Explain of both the query is as follows:

```
Explain of Original query


HashAggregate  (cost=409746.04..409746.83 rows=53 width=15)"
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=2.19..407307.98 rows=487612 width=15)"
        Hash Cond: (facttable.me = dim_me.id)"
        ->  Seq Scan on facttable  (cost=0.00..400601.12 rows=487612 width=12)"
        ->  Hash  (cost=1.53..1.53 rows=53 width=11)"
              ->  Seq Scan on dim_me  (cost=0.00..1.53 rows=53 width=11)"



Explain of rewritten query


Hash Join  (cost=403040.86..403043.19 rows=48 width=15)"
  Hash Cond: (dim_me.id = result_table.me)"
  ->  Seq Scan on dim_me  (cost=0.00..1.53 rows=53 width=11)"
  ->  Hash  (cost=403040.26..403040.26 rows=48 width=12)"
        ->  Subquery Scan result_table  (cost=403039.18..403040.26 rows=48 width=12)"
              ->  HashAggregate  (cost=403039.18..403039.78 rows=48 width=12)"
                    ->  Seq Scan on facttable  (cost=0.00..400601.12 rows=487612 width=12)"
```

Comment: `when dim_me.name = 'k%'` does something completely different than `dim_me.name like 'k%'` in the original query. Can you please post the execution plan (using explain analyze) for both statements? Ideally uploaded to http://explain.depesz.com

Comment: Yes, that is true, the performance of dim_me.name = 'k%' and dim_me.name like 'k%' is completely different. And the performance now between the original query and rewritten query is almost same (using like for both query), but I would like to know, can we rewrite the original query in a way, that performance will be high?

Comment: unless you post the structure of the tables involved, the indexes defined and the execution plan there is not much we can do. Do you have an index on `facctable.me` or `dim_me.name`?

Comment: I have edited my post, and added explain in it. However I do not have any indexes in both facttable and dimension table. The string value name is primary key in dimension table.

Comment: Try an index one `facttable.me` and one on `dim_me.id` (although I doubt the one on dim_me helps as only 53 rows are involved). If you look at the output of `explain analyze` you can also see whether the planner's estimations are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Indexes are not going to help you.

`dim_me` has only 53 rows, so an index will not be faster than a sequential  table scan. And as you process the whole `facttable` anyway, a sequential  table scan will be the fastest possible way here, too. There is just no room for optimization *in your query*.

Of course all the [basic stuff for optimization](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization) applies and might help you.

If you should, in fact, only be interested in some of the rows, you might want to add a `WHERE` clause to the `SELECT` on `facttable`. *Then* an index might help.